# The keybindings for tabbed don't work in i3, why?

Tags: linux, tabbed, i3, tabbed-interface

I have recently changed from XFCE 4 to i3wm and when i tried to launch zathura with tabbed feature like this:

```
nohup tabbed -f zathura -e
```

I get the reader, but when I try to open a new tab `Ctrl + Shift + Return` it just don't work. However, I must say that `ctrl + q` for closing tabs and `ctrl + t` are working. I tried the some in Openbox and in XFCE and all the keybindings work just perfectly just well.

I tried to change the keyboard layout with `setxkbmap`, checking the source code and nothing seems off. Is a problem of i3? How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.